# Невозможно работать с файлами в php7 на linux 16.10

Tags: php, linux, файлы

**Суть проблемы**: имеется скрипт, который должен добавлять в ***file.txt*** информацию, а если этот файл отсутствует, то создать его. На деле файл не создается, а если создать его вручную, то информация в него все равно не попадает. Все остается без изменений.

Прочитал всю главу о правах доступа в книге Котерова "PHP7", но мне это ничего не дало. Ни один скрипт, связанный с работой файлов, не работает. Что делать в таком случае?

Скрипт максимально простой для примера:

```
<?php
    // строка, которую будем записывать
    $text = "Какой-то текст";

    // открываем файл, если файл не существует, делается попытка создать его
    $fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");

    // записываем в файл текст
    fwrite($fp, $text);

    // закрываем
    fclose($fp); 
?>
```

Comment: под каким пользователем работает скрипт и какие права на файл и директории где этот файл лежит?

Comment: get_current_user() выдал меня, как пользователя: "sergeystasko". 
getmyuid() - 1000.

Директория: /var/www/html/mysites/php/TASK/test.php. И в этой же папке file.txt.

Comment: какие прав на файл и директорию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сервер тестовый, то временно сделай следущее:

- открой терминал
- вставь команду `cd /var/www/html/mysites/php/`
- дай полный доступ для записи для всех пользователей `sudo chmod 777 ./TASK -R`

Для выполнения последней команды нужны права администратора

Comment: Все работает! Проблема решена! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите под под каким пользователем запущен скрипт и есть ли у него возможность писать в этот файл. Например работает через fastcgi:

> ps aux|grep php-fpm

Допустим что php-fpm запущен от пользователя www-data, попробуем от имени этого пользователя записать в файл, если конечно у вас есть root на сервере:

> su -m www-data; echo 1 > file.txt

Не забудьте проверить путь до файла, укажите полный путь в скрипте вместо относительного или getcwd() в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  $filename = "base.txt"; 

  $fd = fopen($filename, "a");

  if(!$fd) exit("Ошибка при открытии файла данных");

  $str = "kakoi to "."text"."\r\n";     

  fwrite($fd,$str);
  fclose($fd);


?>
```

не знаю поможет ли тебе, но именно такая ерунда пашет.

Comment: "Ошибка при открытии файла данных" выводит. Т.е. получается, что файл даже не открывается. Хм...

Comment: а ты создал этот файл?

Comment: не юзал линукс, даже не знаю, мб реально что то с правами..